# HOw to droplist this kind of table in google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I create a google sheet like this image :

[my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwg2O.png)

And i want to get a droplist, where i got only name with "X" in yellow, another drop with only green...

I search some Function like FILTER or DGET

Thanks !

Comment: please share a sample copy of your sheet, so experts can work on your question without each having to recreate your data.  Be sure to make the sample sheet editable by all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question wasn't too clear to me, since I wasn't sure if you meant a "droplist" to be used as a dropdown list for data validation.  If so, the result of my solution can be used as the range for the data validation.

Note that my solution is quite interactive.  If you just want a list of all names that have an "X" in the yellow column, and a separate list of all names that have an "X" in the green column, etc., that is easily done with a subset of the broader `FILTER` equation I've provided.

The formula is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(
  FILTER(F2:F999,
    F2:F999<>"X",
    F2:F999<>"",
    IF(L2,D3:D1000="X",ROW(D3:D1000)),
    IF(M2,E3:E1000="X",ROW(D3:D1000)),
    IF(N2,F3:F1000="X",ROW(D3:D1000)),
    IF(O2,G3:G1000="X",ROW(D3:D1000)),
    IF(P2,H3:H1000="X",ROW(D3:D1000)),
    IF(Q2,I3:I1000="X",ROW(D3:D1000))),
  "No matches")
```

It is a basic filter of column F, which has all the names listed, but on alternate rows.  It filters out, with the first two criteria, both blank rows, and any rows that have an X in column F.

Then it adds six criteria, to check the rows below the rows with names, to see if there is an "X" in any of those columns.  The criteria are activated using the checkboxes in L2:Q2.  If a checkbox is off, the filter criteria is set to `ROW(D3:D1000)`, which should equate to TRUE, so as not to filter on that particular column.

(Side note:  I'm not quite clear how that is working.  Without ArrayFormula, I don't think `ROW(D3:D1000)` expands to a column of 998 "1"s, but it seems to satisfy the FILTER's requirement for an array of TRUE/FALSE values that matches the range being filtered.  Maybe someone can explain what is really happening there...)

See my sample sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sGHyRtRrFTA5vNNgH4N2OiN98x7uKG_eyWETWpqTPzg/edit?usp=sharing

Let us know if this is something that helps.  If not, please clarify the outcome you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: @Dino, if the answer clearly addressed your question, please check it as the selected answer, or upvote it, to help others in the future with a similar issue.